# Retrieve single value by id from many to many relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to get a single value (company) from a list of companies that belong to a user with id=x. So far I can get the whole list of companies, but I want to get the single one by its ID.

Thank you very much!

With this I cant get all the companies.

```php
$user = auth('api')->user();
$companies = $user->company;
```

I tried many things, the last one was

```php
$companies = $user->company->where('id', $id);
```

but I got

> "message": "Undefined variable: company",

Comment: show your user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the query builder by adding `()` and extend it with the where clause.

Try this:

```php
$company = $user->company()->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Or if you don't need a collection:

```php
$company = $user->company()->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: @nacho If this worked for you please consider marking this answer as accepted. So other people that experience the same problem can quickly find an answer. This is of course up to you.